# Basic C# object vs object interaction

Tags: c#, oop, object

I'm currently going through various resources and trying to learn C# OOP. I haven't gone through anything on it yet but I had a go at object vs object interaction. Unfortunately it didn't go to plan and I got slightly confused on what objects I should have been referencing. I wanted to create a simple attack method that reduced the health of another object just to get the basics of object vs object interaction down. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog milo = new Dog("Sparky");
            Dog ruffles = new Dog("Ruffles");
            milo.Attack(ruffles);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Dog
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int health = 100;


        public Dog(string theName)
        {
            name = theName;


            public void Attack(Dog theDog)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} attacks {1}.", this.name, theDog);
                LoseHealth(theDog);
            }

            public void LoseHealth()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} loses health!", theDog);
                theDog -= 5;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The code doesn't work at all. Any idea on what I did wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: `LoseHealth` needs a `Dog` parameter and that and `Attack` both need to be moved out of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The code of the dog class is a bit messed up.

The Attack and LoseHealth methods are *in* the constructor.

Instead of referring to the health and name you only refer to theDog.

Have a look at this

```
class Dog
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int health = 100;


    public Dog(string theName)
    {
        name = theName;
    }

    public void Attack(Dog theDog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} attacks {1}.", this.name, theDog.name);
        LoseHealth(theDog);
    }

    public void LoseHealth(Dog theDog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} loses health!", theDog.name);
        theDog.health -= 5;
    }
}
```

Extra OO tip:

It would make more sense to change the attack and LoseHealth methods like this:

```
public void Attack(Dog theDog)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} attacks {1}.", this.name, theDog.name);
    theDog.LoseHealth(5);
}

public void LoseHealth(int damage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} loses health!", name);
    this.health -= damage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `theDog -= -5`. But `theDog` isn't a number. You need to reference the health of the dog. You also need to pass `theDog` into the `LoseHealth()` function. Change it to this:

```
theDog.health -= 5;
```

This uses dot notation to access the health of `theDog`.

But also, your functions are nested in the constructor. Move `Attack()` and `LoseHealth()` so they're in the class, not in the constructor body. You should end up with something like this:

```
class Dog
    {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int health = 100;


    public Dog(string theName)
        {
            name = theName;               
        }
    public void Attack(Dog theDog)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} attacks {1}.", this.name, theDog);
                LoseHealth(theDog);
            }

    public void LoseHealth(Dog theDog)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} loses health!", theDog);
                theDog.health -= 5;
            }
    }
```

By the way, never just say "my code doesn't work". Explain how it doesn't work. Include relevant exception messages if there are any.